# How to wrap multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

example,

```
<div id = "test1">test1</div>
<div id = "test2">test2</div>
```

i want to wrap a parent div like this,

```
<div id="parent_test">
    <div id = "test1">test1</div>
    <div id = "test2">test2</div>
</div>
```

I tried to use jquery `wrap()`, but it only wraps one by one:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$("#test1, #test2").wrapAll($("<div>", { id: "parent_test" }));
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/8xV2M/)

Answer (score 0):

use `.wrapAll()`:

```
$('#test1,#test2').wrapAll('<div id="parent_test" style="color:red;"></div>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EcSN5/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Use jQuery WrapAll method](http://www.visualjquery.net/category/Manipulation/wrapAll)

```
<div id = "test1" class="my-div">test1</div>
<div id = "test2" class="my-div">test2</div>

$('.my-div').wrapAll("<div class='my-wrap'></div>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6eGuG/