# How to use JQuery to Wrap a specific list of div children

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-optimize

I am doing AB testing in google optimize. I need to wrap div from number 5 to 10 but I have not been able to do it:

```
<div class="container active" data-order="1">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<button>11</button>
<div>12</div>
</div>
```

I am using this code to do it but it start wrapping from div number one but I want to start with div number 5 until 10

```
$('.gsw_cf.step.active > div:lt(#)').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped 5to10"/>');
```

anyone knows what should I add?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/);

```
$('.active > div').slice(5,10).wrapAll('<div class="wrapped 5to10"/>');
```

```js
$('.active > div').slice(5,10).wrapAll('<div class="wrapped 5to10"/>');
```

```css
.wrapped{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container active" data-order="1">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<button>11</button>
<div>12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works where i use this function:

```
$('div[data-order="1"]').each(function(){
    $(this).children(".input_wrapper.text").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper' />");
});
```

I found that solution in http://jsfiddle.net/QWHYK/
and [Wrapping sets of elements from a list in DIVs using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386796/wrapping-sets-of-elements-from-a-list-in-divs-using-jquery)

There is also, another solution in [How to wrap multiple divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009414/how-to-wrap-multiple-divs)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).